# Recurring Events in Basecamp API

Tags: api, events, basecamp, recurring-events

Is there a way to include the recurrence options as part of the event objects in these endpoints:
https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/calendar_events.md

I'm working on adding support for Basecamp into Sunrise Calendar and supporting recurring events will be awesome.

Thank you,

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

We don't support recurring events through the API at the moment - sorry about that.  Hopefully we'll be able to add that support in the future.

Comment: Hello Jim, do you have any updates on this issue? More and more users are asking for this integration with Basecamp and this is holding us back. Thank you.